# Multi level inheritance python - 'CheckingAccount' object has no attribute 'balance'

Tags: python

I am working on a python project. All was working well when I just had one level of inheritance but once I added `SavingAccount` and `CheckingAccount` which should be a child of `BankAccount` which is a child of Customer I started to get the following error: `'CheckingAccount' object has no attribute 'balance'`

I assumed I would do the second layer of inheritance the same as the first but maybe I must be missing. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,firstName, lastName, social):
        self.firstName = firstName 
        self.lastName = lastName 
        self.social = social 

    def setfirstName(self,firstName):
        self.firstName = firstName

    def setlastName(self,lastName):
        self.lastName = lastName

    def __str__(self):
        self.name = "{},{} (SSN:{})".format(self.firstName, self.lastName,self.social)
        return self.name 


class BankAccount(Customer):
    from random import randint
    n = 10
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    accountNumber = randint(range_start, range_end)

    def __init__(self,customer,balance = 0):
        self.customer = customer
        self.balance = balance 

    def setCustomer(self,customer,accountNumber):
        self.customer = customer
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber 

    def getCustomer(self,customer,accountNumber):
        return self.customer, self.accountNumber

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance + amount
        return self.balance

    def withdrawal(self, amount):
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
        return self.balance

    def __str__(self):
        customer = "{} account number: {}, balance: ${}".format(self.customer,self.accountNumber,self.balance)
        return customer 
class CheckingAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, bankAccount):
        self.bankAccount = bankAccount



    def applyAnnualInterest(self):
        excess = self.balance - 10000
        if excess > 0:
            interest = (excess * .02)
            self.balance = self.balance + interest
            return self.balance
        else:
            return self.balance


class SavingAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, bankAccount):
        self.bankAccount = bankAccount


    def applyAnnualInterest(self):
        interest = (self.balance * .05)
        self.balance = self.balance + interest
        return self.balance


def main():

    alin = Customer('Alin', 'Smith', '111-11-1111')
    mary = Customer('Mary', 'Lee', '222-22-2222')
    alinAccnt = CheckingAccount(alin)
    maryAccnt = SavingAccount(mary)

    alinAccnt.deposit(20000)
    print(alinAccnt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the parent; try:

```
class CheckingAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, bankAccount):
        super(CheckingAccount, self).__init__()
        self.bankAccount = bankAccount
```

Don't forget the intermediate class too!

```
class BankAccount(Customer):
    def __init__(self,customer,balance = 0):
        super(BankAccount, self).__init__()
        self.customer = customer
        self.balance = balance
```

This will ensure the parent constructors get called too.